# Javascript Doesn't work on FireFox

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get this script working in FireFox, and it seems to only wanna work in Chrome. I'm guessing it's due to webkit so I attempted converting it to a standard gradient, but it doesn't work at all. What is wrong with the script?

Webkit:

```
var grad = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, transparent), color-stop(1, #' + color + '))';
```

Standard:

```
var grad = 'linear-gradient(to left, color-stop(0, #' + color + '), color-stop(1, transparent))';
```

Live script: **http://jsfiddle.net/LThhd/12/**

Comment: The var grad doesn't work so there is no gradient showing up in firefox, only chrome

Comment: Each browser has its own syntax. See [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: You mean to say the webkit prefix doesn't work in a mozilla browser? Madness!

Comment: I updated it with the -moz but it still doesn't wanna work.

    var grad = '-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, color-stop(0, #' + color + '), color-stop(1, transparent))';

Comment: Also, this would have better performance using canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-moz` prefix to make it work in firefox. For complete browser compatibility, all the following CSS rules are recommended (obviously, replacing colors as needed):

```
background-color: #444444;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999);
```

In order, these target the following browsers:

1. Old browsers that don't support gradients
2. Safari 4.*, 5.0, and old versions of Chrome
3. Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+, iOS 5+
4. Firefox 3.6-15
5. Opera 11.10-12.00
6. Firefox 16+, IE10, Opera 12.50+

(source: http://css3please.com)

Answer (score 1):

-moz-linear-gradient is the correct name for gradients in firefox

Useful tool for CSS-Gradient creation: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

dont you have to use the -moz- prefix ....
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient